# RxJS delay in updating the next value when using filter()

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have this piece of code:

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    changes$ = new Subject<number>();
    current$ = this.changes$
        .scan((x, y) => x + y, 0)
        .filter((x) => x >= 0);
    constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.changes$.next(0);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
    <button (click)="changes$.next(-1)">-1</button>
    <button (click)="changes$.next(1)">+1</button>

    <div>
        <span>{{ current$ | async }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>{{ current$ | async }}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>{{ current$ | async }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem was that I didn't want to go below 0 so I added the filter operator. This solved my problem but when I get to 0 and press like 10 times the minus button and then press the add button again, it doesn't get updated unless I press the add button a lot of times.

Why is this? How can I solve that?

Example:

[image: The problem in GIF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all - as Deepak said you need to move it to the `scan()`. The reason being is that when `changes$` subject emits new value `scan()` will still continue to count whatever it emits including negative numbers, but you just won't see it from behind the `filter()`. You need precisely to stop counting if you don't want your counter to go below 0, not masking its output by `filter()`.

Also, you don't need to manually emit the first value, you don't need constructor and ngAfterViewInit calling ChangeDetectorRef. This all is totally unnecessary.

Below is the fixed code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    changes$ = new Subject<number>();
    current$ = this.changes$
        .startWith(0)
        .scan((x, y) => (x + y) >= 0 ? x + y : 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code & explanation. Yeah, I had my doubts about ngAfterViewInit and ChangeDetectorRef. I was basicly copying this code: https://github.com/matiboy/angular2-observables-weatherdata/blob/single_component/src/app/app.component.ts, found it on a YouTube video. But that gave me error, so I searched the error and found the (dirty) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the scan. The reason is that every time a value is emitted the scan will be processed no matter whether it is filtered or not.

```
.scan((x, y) => (x + y) >= 0 ? x + y : 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Marked Alexander's answer as correct because of the explanation.